# BizTalk Deployment - Outbound Logical Port remains Unbound

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations, send-port

I have a BizTalk solution which gets deployed using UDeploy.

After deployment, in one orchestration, one particular outbound logical port doesn't get bound to its send port. The send port in question, is present in the drop down; but the Send Port selected is `None`. All other logical ports (inbound and outbound) in the application do get bound to their respective physical ports.

Why is this and what can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it has nothing to do with UDeploy.

The problem is in the Binding File that goes with the installation.  It could be the specific binding is missing, there's a misspelling, an name has changed.